# Is that possible to customize "files export path"?

Tags: magento2, custom, importexport, paths

System - Data Transfer - Export

The files export is in `/magento/var/export/`. Can we custom this path?

And if we can custom. How to?

Comment: I don't think you can. I don't get what you want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course customize it, as everything in magento.

Step 1 : Check the url triggered by the export to find the controller used.
Step 2 : Analyse the controller code to find where the var/export path is used.
Step 3 : Make a preference from that class and change according to your own requirements.

That being said i don't see the goal behind all that.